# Can Python cooperate with another applications?

Tags: python

Can Python cooperate with applications like  **Chrome**?

Something like:

```
from Tkinter import *

from (straightAccesToApps) import (straightAccesToApps)

main = Tk()

def runChrome():
    straightAccesToApps('C:\\Desktop\Chrome').run()
    main.quit()

Button(main, text="Chrome", command=runChrome).pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: yes python can do it

Comment: For working with additional processes, subprocess is good way to go - https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/

Answer (score 3):

Yes python can do it in many ways:

1.Via modules like [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html):

```
url = 'http://www.python.org/'

# Open URL in a new tab, if a browser window is already open.
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url + 'doc/')

# Open URL in new window, raising the window if possible.
webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

---

2.Via `os.system` or `subprocess.call`:

```
import os
os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -ArgumentList @( '-incognito', 'www.site.com'" )
```

---

3.Via powershell but that is a bit of a overkill

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", ". \"./SamplePowershell\";", 'Start-Process "chrome.exe" "www.google.com"'])
```

Comment: You can use `string = shlex.split(string)` to obtain the string expected by subprocess.call().

Comment: thanks, i got it, why do you always delete your comments? It's like the fourth time you write this. @lecaruyer

Answer (score 0):

Via selenium webdriver, de facto industry standard: http://www.seleniumhq.org

Comment: I think that this answer is too specific, he doesn't only want to open a browser, the question was about python cooperating with other applications, not just web browser